# The second printf isn't working, need help. (C lang)

Tags: c, linked-list

What is the problem here? It prints the first printf but it doesn't print the next statement
Help appreciated.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int Data;
  struct node *Link;
};

//close struct
void insertAtEnd(struct node *Itcstd, int iData)
{
  while (Itcstd->Link != NULL )
    Itcstd = Itcstd->Link;

  Itcstd->Link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  Itcstd->Link->Link = NULL;
  Itcstd->Link->Data = iData;
} //close insertAtEnd

int main()
{
  struct node *EHead;

  EHead = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  EHead->Link = NULL;
  EHead->Data = 4;

  printf("EHead link: %p Ehead Data: %d\n", EHead->Link, EHead->Data);
  insertAtEnd(EHead, 10);
  printf("EHead link: %p Ehead Data: %d\n", EHead->Link, EHead->Data);

  return 0;
} //close main
```

Comment: first of all: don't cast the result of malloc. Second, when you use "malloc" always free the memory, whenever you don't need it to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Works for me... It must be something with your environment?

Comment: So far about badly formatted code ...? ;-))

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's a good code, it works for me perfectly. (I can see two lines.)

Comment: I agree. Don't know why there is a -1. There's clearly no infinite loop. See http://ideone.com/boB9cA

Comment: Although a "correct" answer, this would have suited better as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The code runs fine, without any memory issues.

The only point to mention is that the conversion specifier for `printf()`ing a pointer (`%p`) is defined for `void *` only. Having told the compiler to be pedantic (option `-pedantic` for gcc) it would have notified you about this.

So this

```
printf("EHead link: %p Ehead Data: %d\n", EHead->Link, EHead->Data);
```

shall be this

```
printf("EHead link: %p Ehead Data: %d\n", (void *) EHead->Link, EHead->Data);
```

This, btw, is one of the rare cases in C where casting can not be avoided.

Comment: the first printf works because `EHead->Link` is NULL, which is of type `void`.

Answer (score 1):

code is elegant , and is working fine for me i checked it on windows (codeblocks MinGW gcc 4.7 , turbo c++)
linux (gcc 4.8.1 ) and it works perfectly . 
which environment are you using ?